Cache behaviour in Spark on rerun
I have a DataFrame that is created by reading data files from the cloud, which are in terabytes. After reading the data, I apply a few filters and cache the DataFrame. The process looks like this: read -> filter -> cache.
If I change the filter and rerun the entire code, will Spark overwrite the DataFrame with the new filtered data and cache it again or will it retain the previously cached data with the old filters?
From my testing, Spark uses the new filter and overwrites the DataFrame with the updated data. I'm curious about how Spark knows to overwrite (ie. rerun) the DataFrame when it has already been cached.

This question is similar to: If I cache a Spark Dataframe and then overwrite the reference, will the original data frame still be cached?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Show the code pls.
